# Change Oracle IP

Tags: oracle, configuration, connections

If I change Oracle database server IP , what problems may be caused and how to solve them?

1. modify `hosts` file
2. modify `tnsnames.ora` file
3. modify `listener.ora` file
4. modify clients' `tnsnames.ora` files

As I know it is not necessary to have `listener.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` files on the database server; it *is* necessary if you need to connect to another database. Am I right?

I have single-instance database, version 11.2.0.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of what you have listed as required is necessary if you use fully qualified domain names in the `TNSNAMES` and client `TNSNAMES` files, and you are using a Windows domain.

This is the reason why hard coding IP addresses is a maintenance headache.  Instead of:

```
MY_DB=   (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=192.168.0.2)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVICE_NAME=MY_DB.HOME.LOCAL)
    )   )
```

Use:

```
MY_DB=   (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=DB_MACHINE_NAME.HOME.LOCAL)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVICE_NAME=MY_DB.HOME.LOCAL)
    )   )
```